# Date formatting issue in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Im trying to write simple tests which will allow to input date for specific car search on page which allows for checking information about vehicles (in future i want to create dynamic data change so it will check all possibilites and find a proper date):

https://historiapojazdu.gov.pl/

but when i try to send any date even static value, instead of numbers input I recive "**.**.____" in response.

```
public class VinTest {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int DD=01;
    int MM=01;
    int YYYY=2000;
}

@Test
public void date_FF() {
    WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //   calendar.setTime(new Date());
    //   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,10);
    //  System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    ffDriver.get("https://historiapojazdu.gov.pl/");
    WebElement NrRej = ffDriver.findElement(By.id("_historiapojazduportlet_WAR_historiapojazduportlet_:rej"));
    WebElement Vin = ffDriver.findElement(By.id("_historiapojazduportlet_WAR_historiapojazduportlet_:vin"));
    WebElement DataRej = ffDriver.findElement(By.id("_historiapojazduportlet_WAR_historiapojazduportlet_:data"));
    WebElement SubmitButton = ffDriver.findElement(By.id("_historiapojazduportlet_WAR_historiapojazduportlet_:btnSprawdz"));
    NrRej.sendKeys("PN58210");
    Vin.sendKeys("W0L0TGF48Y6064323");
    DataRej.sendKeys("01012000");
   // SubmitButton.click();

    ffDriver.close();

}
```

}

Could someone tell me how to avoid conversion of "01012000" into "**.**.____"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the date box before writing inside a date.

```
DataRej.click();
DataRej.sendKeys("01012000");
```